# How can I convert a json in geojson format?

Tags: json, python-2.7, geojson

I have seen other similar questions and with good answers, only that the interntarlo in my program tells me error, I may be wrong, the process is as follows. And I think that is correct.

```
from sys import argv
from os.path import exists
import json 
jdata({"metadata":{"resultset":
{"offset":1,"count":125210,"limit":25}},"results":
[{"elevation":139,"mindate":"1948-01-01","maxdate":"2014-01-
01","latitude":31.5702,"name":"ABBEVILLE, AL US","datacoverage":0.8813,"id":"COOP:010008","elevationUnit":"METERS","longitude":-85.2482},{"elevation":249.3,"mindate":"1938-01-01","maxdate":"2015-11-01","latitude":34.2553,"name":"ADDISON, AL US","datacoverage":0.5059,"id":"COOP:010063","elevationUnit":"METERS","longitude":-87.1814},{"elevation":302.1,"mindate":"1940-05-01","maxdate":"1962-03-01","latitude":34.41667,"name":"ADDISON CENTRAL TOWER, AL US","datacoverage":0.9658,"id":"COOP:010071","elevationUnit":"METERS","longitude":-87.31667},{"elevation":172.2,"mindate":"1995-04-01","maxdate":"2015-11-01","latitude":33.17833,"name":"ALABASTER SHELBY CO AIRPORT, AL US","datacoverage":0.8064,"id":"COOP:010116","elevationUnit":"METERS","longitude":-86.78167},{"elevation":183.8,"mindate":"1949-01-01","maxdate":"1949-12-01","latitude":34.6891,"name":"BELLE MINA, AL US","datacoverage":1,"id":"COOP:010117","elevationUnit":"METERS","longitude":-86.8819},{"elevation":34.1,"mindate":"1935-05-01","maxdate":"1936-11-01","latitude":31.13333,"name":"ALAGA, AL US","datacoverage":0.2624,"id":"COOP:010125","elevationUnit":"METERS","longitude":-85.06667},{"elevation":53.3,"mindate":"1940-11-01","maxdate":"2014-12-01","latitude":32.2322,"name":"ALBERTA, AL US","datacoverage":0.9888,"id":"COOP:010140","elevationUnit":"METERS","longitude":-87.4104},{"elevation":348.1,"mindate":"1931-01-01","maxdate":"1977-06-01","latitude":34.23333,"name":"ALBERTVILLE, AL US","datacoverage":0.9535,"id":"COOP:010148","elevationUnit":"METERS","longitude":-86.16667},{"elevation":195.1,"mindate":"1969-10-01","maxdate":"2015-11-01","latitude":32.9452,"name":"ALEXANDER CITY, AL US","datacoverage":0.9946,"id":"COOP:010160","elevationUnit":"METERS","longitude":-85.948},{"elevation":200.9,"mindate":"1942-11-01","maxdate":"1969-10-01","latitude":32.98333,"name":"ALEXANDER CITY 6 NE, AL US","datacoverage":0.9629,"id":"COOP:010163","elevationUnit":"METERS","longitude":-85.86667},{"elevation":59.4,"mindate":"1940-01-01","maxdate":"2015-11-01","latitude":33.1272,"name":"ALICEVILLE, AL US","datacoverage":0.9144,"id":"COOP:010178","elevationUnit":"METERS","longitude":-88.155},{"elevation":50.3,"mindate":"1980-05-01","maxdate":"2015-11-01","latitude":33.21,"name":"ALICEVILLE L AND D, AL US","datacoverage":0.9883,"id":"COOP:010184","elevationUnit":"METERS","longitude":-88.2878},{"elevation":76.2,"mindate":"1938-01-01","maxdate":"2015-11-01","latitude":31.3071,"name":"ANDALUSIA 3 W, AL US","datacoverage":0.9744,"id":"COOP:010252","elevationUnit":"METERS","longitude":-86.5226},{"elevation":208.8,"mindate":"2004-07-01","maxdate":"2015-11-01","latitude":34.9093,"name":"ANDERSON, AL US","datacoverage":1,"id":"COOP:010260","elevationUnit":"METERS","longitude":-87.2746},{"elevation":220.1,"mindate":"1948-01-01","maxdate":"1949-03-01","latitude":33.66667,"name":"ANNISTON, AL US","datacoverage":1,"id":"COOP:010267","elevationUnit":"METERS","longitude":-85.83333},{"elevation":181.1,"mindate":"1948-01-01","maxdate":"2015-11-01","latitude":33.5872,"name":"ANNISTON METROPOLITAN AIRPORT, AL US","datacoverage":0.9816,"id":"COOP:010272","elevationUnit":"METERS","longitude":-85.8556},{"elevation":227.1,"mindate":"1938-01-01","maxdate":"1983-10-01","latitude":34.06667,"name":"ARLEY 1 S, AL US","datacoverage":0.9691,"id":"COOP:010338","elevationUnit":"METERS","longitude":-87.23333},{"elevation":311.5,"mindate":"1948-01-01","maxdate":"2013-11-01","latitude":33.2941,"name":"ASHLAND, AL US","datacoverage":0.8872,"id":"COOP:010369","elevationUnit":"METERS","longitude":-85.7788},{"elevation":180.1,"mindate":"1941-06-01","maxdate":"1973-06-01","latitude":33.85,"name":"ASHVILLE, AL US","datacoverage":0.9429,"id":"COOP:010377","elevationUnit":"METERS","longitude":-86.33333},{"elevation":210,"mindate":"1948-01-01","maxdate":"2015-11-01","latitude":34.7752,"name":"ATHENS, AL US","datacoverage":0.5632,"id":"COOP:010390","elevationUnit":"METERS","longitude":-86.9508},{"elevation":219.5,"mindate":"1955-10-01","maxdate":"1991-07-01","latitude":34.8,"name":"ATHENS 2, AL US","datacoverage":0.9442,"id":"COOP:010395","elevationUnit":"METERS","longitude":-86.98333},{"elevation":220.1,"mindate":"1958-05-01","maxdate":"1958-06-01","latitude":34.8,"name":"ATHENS COURTHOUSE, AL US","datacoverage":0.998,"id":"COOP:010398","elevationUnit":"METERS","longitude":-86.96667},{"elevation":91.4,"mindate":"1940-01-01","maxdate":"2015-11-01","latitude":31.182,"name":"ATMORE, AL US","datacoverage":0.7103,"id":"COOP:010402","elevationUnit":"METERS","longitude":-87.439},{"elevation":67.1,"mindate":"1965-01-01","maxdate":"1982-10-01","latitude":31.01667,"name":"ATMORE, AL US","datacoverage":0.967,"id":"COOP:010407","elevationUnit":"METERS","longitude":-87.51667},{"elevation":223.1,"mindate":"1931-01-01","maxdate":"1970-12-01","latitude":32.6,"name":"AUBURN, AL US","datacoverage":0.9917,"id":"COOP:010422","elevationUnit":"METERS","longitude":-85.5}]}
script, in_file, out_file = argv
data = json.loads(jdata)
geo_map = {"type":"FeatureCollection"}
```

It is here that will not let me continue

```
geojson = {
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
{
"type": "Feature",
"geometry" : {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [point["lon"], point["lat"]],
    },
"properties" : {
"mindate":[],
"maxdate":[],
"name":[],
"datacoverage":[],
"id":[],
"elevationUnit":[],
} 
for Point in data]

output = open(out_file, 'w')
json.dump(geojson, output)

print geojson
```

My English is not very good, i hope you understand and can help me please.

Comment: you can get the help of google translate :)

Comment: Was about to say the same :)

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake, that's what I did!

Comment: Could you help me on this please